# querySelector not working in Shadow DOM in Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, polymer-2.x

In Polymer 2, Im trying to change a property called `urls` that is in the shadow DOM. I try to acceess it in `var loader`. I have tried:

```
var loader = document.querySelector( '#urls' );
var loader = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#urls');
var loader = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#urls');
var loader = this.$.urls;
var loader = this.$$.urls;
var loader = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#urls')
```

But none works. What Im doing wrong?

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="ami-loader2.html">

<dom-module id="my-view2">
  <template is="dom-bind" id="urls">
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <ami-loader2 urls="[[urls]]"></ami-loader2>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyView2 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-view2'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView2.is, MyView2);

    var t2 = ['36444280', '36444294', '36444308', '36444322', '36444336'];
    var urlsstring = t2.map( function( v ) {

      return 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/FNNDSC/data/master/dicom/adi_brain/' + v;

    } );

    //var loader = document.querySelector( '#urls' );
    //var loader = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#urls')
    //var loader = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#urls')
    var loader = this.$.urls

    loader.urls = urlsstring;

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I can see `<ami-loader2>` in the document here:
[image: ami-loader2 in the document]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to access an element via an ID you actually have to provide an id :p

`<ami-loader2 id="loader" urls="[[urls]]"></ami-loader2>`

so then you can access the element with `this.$.loader` or if you wish you can do `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#loader')`

This will give you back the ELEMENT. So you can then use functions/apis this element provides.

But as your are using Data-Binding to actually give some data to this elements it's much easier to actually select this value as the "raw" data. Which would be just `this.url`.

And you can actually just do `this.urls = 'http://my-url.com'` and it will be set for this element.

Be sure to properly define data you wish to bind as properties as well and that all your code is within your class.

```
<script>
class MyView2 extends Polymer.Element {

    static get is() { return 'my-view2'; }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            urls: {
                type: String,
                reflectToAttribute: true
            }
        };
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        // your code 
    }

}

customElements.define(MyView2.is, MyView2);
</script>
```

Just as a reference. You would be using the element like this
`<my-view2 urls="http://my-path.com">...</my-view2>`

Following is very specific to your code and my interpretation on what I think you want to do.

if you only wish to set the variable dynamically inside your element and you don't want to actually change it within your ami-loader2. You could remove the `reflectToAttribute: true` but keep the rest and just use `this.urls = 'http://my-path.com'`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I added the id in `<ami-loader2 id="loader" urls="[[urls]]"></ami-loader2>` and tried to access the element with `console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#loader'));` but I still get the error `Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined`. I dont know whats going on :(

Comment: you can only access `this` INSIDE your class... so make sure to call it inside the function ready or connectedCallback... I edited my answer to show a more complete class

Comment: glad I could help :)